# Reverse Routing /:controller/:id

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

Keeping this short and sweet: I can quite easily specify something like the following in routes.php and make urls of the desired form work:

```
Router::connect('/:controller/:id',
    array('action'=>'item'),
    array('id'=>'[0-9]+')
);
```

However, the routes are still generated as '/:controller/item/:id' by Cake.  Is there a simple way to have Cake's reverse routing make urls without including the action?  Or do I just have to go through my application and manually replace the relevant arrays with "/:controller/$id"?

Comment: Can you give some examples you are trying to reverse that aren't working? And is it routing properly in the first place? It all looks good to me.

Comment: This sort of array passed to Html->link: array('controller'=>':controller', 'action'=>'item', $id) seems to give me a link to /controller/item/$id.  I don't know whether that's expected and I'm just trying too hard - routes in the /controller/$id form do work.  I did find a possible solution which I'll post below, but anyone who really understands how Cake routing works can still feel free to enlighten me as to how I *should* be doing this kind of thing!

Comment: `array('controller'=>'videos', 'action'=>'item', $id)` should match and become `/videos/$id`. Did you try with `:controller` in your HTML link, because that won't work. You still need to define the controller when creating the link. Reverse routing is changing `/videos/$id` to `array('controller'=>'videos', 'action'=>'item', $id)`, which should also work.

Comment: I'll have a play around and let you know what happens! Thanks!

Comment: @jeremyharris It's no good, I just can't seem to get the urls to be generated without "/item/" appearing in the middle! Maybe I should just bite the bullet and go and investigate the Cake code, I clearly need the secrets of routes demystifying for me...

Comment: What you have should work fine. It's even a basic example in the book. When you visit `/videos/2` do you at least get there? If so, it might just be a problem in your route order.

Comment: Yes, such a link works, it just isn't generated back like that.  I couldn't see a prior route that would mess with things, but I'll go through it one more time with a fine comb.  Very puzzling!

Comment: Hi, same issue here. Did you get it solved using named parameters? I'd rather use named params than the asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution to my problem - if I specify a route like so:

```
Router::connect('/videos/*',
    array('controller'=>'videos', 'action'=>'item'),
    array('pass'=>array('id'))
);
```

It does seem to reverse route this back to /videos/$id.

I still don't know what the difference between this and my original attempt is though, and why the original is (or is under some circumstances) harder to route!  So any Cake routing expertise that anyone can send my way would still be very welcome.

Comment: You, my man, are doing it right, no experts needed. As [this book example explains](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action), that's the way to go.

Little advice on site-wide link changes - if you wanted to change the way links are created, you might want to override the main AppHelper::link or AppHelper::url methods.

Your original route probably doesn't work because your /:controller/:id is defined AFTER the core's /:controller/:action/:id - first one takes precedence.